# MySQL syntax error in selecting multiple columns with the WHERE delimiter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database

I have a rather simple query to work with my ajax app, but it gives the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, price FROM products WHERE id='asfasfasf1'' at line 1

I'm stumbled by this as I simply can't see the syntax error anywhere:

```
echo json_encode($this->query("SELECT name, desc, price FROM products WHERE id='".$id."';"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

query() is as follows:

```
function query($query){
        $link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        $connected = mysql_select_db($this->database, $link);
        if(!$connected){
            die("Error: selecting database.");
        }
        $q = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$q){
            return "Error: ".mysql_error();
        }
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
        return $result;
    }
```

Naturally, this is inside an object, but that shouldn't have anything to do with it. All the fields are correct, database can be connected to since the query() is used multiple times with other code and works well. Please help.

Comment: 1) i don't think you have to end your SQL statement with a semicolon 2) are you sure that the commas are actually commas 3) have you tried outputing the generated query and running it in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a keyword in SQL (for sorting in descending order.) If you're going to use it as a column name, try quoting it:

```
$this->query("SELECT name, `desc`, price FROM products WHERE id='".$id."';")
```

See [the MySQL manual on reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for an almost identical example, and more details on how to deal with keywords.

Or you could just rename your column to "description", say. Much as quoting is the "right" solution, it's generally helpful to avoid using reserved words as column names if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't notice that (I even used it to sort the data before)! I'm going to change the table name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance `id` has to be in double quotes, not single ones.

BTW, be careful with this sort of thing because it makes SQL injection attacks really easy.

Comment: don't worry, I have escaped the input and this functionality is only accessible to the admin :-)